# How to make a full image inside href be clickable

Tags: html, css, less

simple question, I'm doing something wrong, but didn't get what the problem here. I want to make images clickable as it was links, but this isn't working properly, with the link staying in the middle only, not staying the full image as I want. Someone could help?

```
<div>
<ul class="principaisCategorias">
    <li class="itemCategoria">
        <div class="imagesItemCategoria">
            <a data-bind="ccLink:{route: '/category/ar-condicionado-portatil'}">
                <img src="/file/general/imageItemCategoria.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my css:

```
div{
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        &.principaisCategorias{
            width: 102%;
            height: 450px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            .itemCategoria{
                list-style-type: none;
                margin-top: 2px;
                margin-left: 2%;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
                margin-right: 2%;
                height: 140px;
                width: 45%;
                background-color: mediumturquoise;
                .imagesItemCategoria {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                    img, a{
                        display: block;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        max-height:100%; 
                        max-width:100%;
                    }
                    a{
                        display: inline-block;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `width: 100%` from the `img` so that the image will *auto-adjust*...

Comment: Already tried this. It solve the problem, but the image broke. The right side gave a blank space.

Comment: try `object-fit: cover` on the `img`?

Comment: No changes. still get a blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to run the code initially none of the inner styles were being applied. This is because your CSS is nested like SASS or SCSS. When I refactored to ordinary CSS syntax it started working better.

As far as the `a` link behavior issue, you do not have an `href` attribute on that element so it behaves more or less like a `<span>` tag. There were also several other unnecessary styles in there. This is all I needed to get it to behave as I expected:

```
.imagesItemCategoria a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Full code and working demo:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.principaisCategorias{
    width: 102%;
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.itemCategoria{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: mediumturquoise;
}
.imagesItemCategoria {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.imagesItemCategoria a {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.imagesItemCategoria img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="principaisCategorias">
    <li class="itemCategoria">
        <div class="imagesItemCategoria">
            <a data-bind="ccLink:{route: '/category/ar-condicionado-portatil'}">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: One last comment... it is not a good idea to target bare `div` selector as you will start getting many other unintended side effects if you use any other divs in your site. I added the class `.wrapper` to that top level div and changed the CSS to target that class instead.

Comment: That's solve the problem of the blank space in the right but now get me another problem. The images should have some margin from each other, and in your solution, one div is above other, killing the margin top/bot

Comment: Please provide some kind of visual of what you are going for. It is not easy to see the intent based on your code alone.

Comment: Target: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/313163944724267009/555828585785458710/unknown.png
My code now:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/313163944724267009/555828767721783326/unknown.png

Comment: There is a fixed height on `ul.principaisCategorias` as well as `display: flex;`. Flex will change the spacing and dimensions of the children. I suggest updating the code with a more complete example, the code you provided had only one element. Also add the intended design to the question too.

Comment: The code is a component of a full website. So the others ```<li>``` as the same of the first that I sampled here.
The ```height``` in ```ul.principaisCategorias``` is the height of the component.
The ```display:flex``` is needed to make the ```justify-content``` and the ```flex-wrap``` to work

Comment: Your question `How to make a full image inside href be clickable` has been answered by me I think.  In general if there are more issues than just that, you should provide all the code and intended outcome in the question. Otherwise make a new question.